# How to access JSON object without knowing its name (and that is not in an array)

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, getjson

My problem is rather simple, at least I hope so, but I just cannot find the solution. I have a JSON string, which I got from a get request to a server.

Exemple of my JSON :

```
"body":[
{
   "_id":"70:ee:50:05:00:aa",
   "place":{
      "location":[
         2.4358958,
         49.503012
      ],
      "altitude":89,
      "timezone":"Europe/Paris"
   },
   "mark":8,
   "measures":{
      "02:00:00:04:f8:6a":{
         "res":{
            "1431926951":[
               7.9,
               83
            ]
         },
      "type":[
         "temperature",
         "humidity"
         ]
      },
      "70:ee:50:05:00:aa":{
         "res":{
            "1431932787":[
               1009.4
            ]
         },
         "type":[
            "pressure"
         ]
      }
  },
  "modules":[
     "02:00:00:04:f8:6a"
  ]
},
```

I need to accessthe temperature value, so following this example I would do this :                `$value = body->measures->02:00:00:04:f8:6a->res->1431926951[0].`

I know i can't just do this : `measures->02:00:00:04:f8:6a`. The cool thing is that this difficulty can be solved doing this : `$module = body->modules[0]` and then I can use this variable.
So it would look like this : `body->measures->$module->res->1431926951[0].`

What I can't seem to do though is the final step : `res->1431926951[0]`. This number seem completely random I can't find this value anywhere else in the JSON so I can't use the same trick I did for `02:00:00:04:f8:6a.` 
So my question is how can I access the first value of the array located inside the object "**1431926951**" without knowing its name ?

Thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

EDIT : here is the code I am using in PHP

```
$results = json_decode($resp);
foreach($results->body as $result){
    $id = $result->_id;
    $lat = $result->place->location[0];
    $lng = $result->place->location[1];
    $module = $result->modules[0];
    $type = $result->measures->$module->type[0];
    $value = "1431926951";
    //$test = $result->measures->$module->res->$value[0];
    /*$res = $result->measures[$result->measures[0]]->res;
    $test = $res[Object.keys($res)[0]][0];*/
    echo 'Id: '.$id.' - Lat: '.$lat.' - Lng: '.$lng.' - test: '.$test."<br>";
}
```

Comment: why you are not using JSON.parse(json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access with the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys) to the name of the property in JavaScript.

```
var res = obj.body.measures[ obj.body.modules[0] ].res;
console.log( res[ Object.keys(res)[0] ][0]); // prints 7.9
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r8d46g62/)

**EDIT (PHP version, only 2 lines):**

With PHP is the same but using [**key**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) and [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php) ([json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) returns [stdClass](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php))

```
$res = $obj->body->measures->{ $obj->body->modules[0] }->res;
echo $res->{ key( (array) $res ) }[0]; // prints 7.9
```

[See demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/87bd3bc1c1fb4d61d1b9275ffe6a1353058135ef)

Hope help.

Comment: Your solution creates an error :"Cannot use object of type stdClass as array". I am going to edit the question, I will add my code, maybe I am doing a mistake somewhere else and it will help you.

Comment: Because I didn't know that you want in PHP. I have edited my answer. See the PHP Version.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonvar = { key: { key1: "value 1", key2: "value 2" } };
var key = Object.keys(jsonvar)[0];
```

This is how we can get the json key from the given json object using javascript.

**Explaination**: Lets say you have a json variable in javascript named `jsonvar` which is holding some `json` data. Now, to access the first `key` contained in `parent json`, then make use of `array` as shown above.

`Object.keys(jsonvar)[0]`

will return the json key: `"key"`. We are accessing the jsonvar to access the first key which corresponds to position `[0]`.

*Hope this could solve your problem.*

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer ? I don't understand how this would solve my problem. Maybe you could show me the implementation of your solution on my problem ? And if you know the PHP implementation it would be even better.

Comment: @PiggyGenius, i have edit/update the answer with the relevant explaination is support. I have posted the code for javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it in PHP:

```
<?php

$ob = '
{
"body":[
{
   "_id":"70:ee:50:05:00:aa",
   "place":{
      "location":[
         2.4358958,
         49.503012
      ],
      "altitude":89,
      "timezone":"Europe/Paris"
   },
   "mark":8,
   "measures":{
      "02:00:00:04:f8:6a":{
         "res":{
            "1431926951":[
               7.9,
               83
            ]
         },
      "type":[
         "temperature",
         "humidity"
         ]
      },
      "70:ee:50:05:00:aa":{
         "res":{
            "1431932787":[
               1009.4
            ]
         },
         "type":[
            "pressure"
         ]
      }
  },
  "modules":[
     "02:00:00:04:f8:6a"
  ]
}
]
}';

//turn the json into a PHP object
$ob = json_decode($ob);

//pre-defined array of known module names
$modules = array("02:00:00:04:f8:6a", "70:ee:50:05:00:aa");

//loop through each moduke
foreach($modules as $module){
    //get the 'res' property for that module
    $res = $ob->body[0]->measures->$module->res;
    //get a list of the object properties
    $properties = get_object_vars($res);
    //select the first property (we don't know the name) uising the current() function
    $firstProperty = current($properties);
    //and print it out
    echo "The first property of $module is: ";
    print_r($firstProperty);
    echo "<br/><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer such a detailed solution. I tried the solution of Pedro Gamez before yours and it was working. But maybe I will need to use your solution later, thank you very much anyway